# Why was my answer deleted? Shouldn't moderators explain their decisions?

Tags: support

I have a question about my Ask Ubuntu post: [How do I set my clock in Windows to UTC / localtime?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/232405/how-do-i-set-my-clock-in-windows-to-utc-localtime/792943#792943)

I'm posting this question after asking support if they could provide more info on why was my answer deleted. 
My answer was:

> If hexafraction's answer didn't work, you're probably running a x64 Windows. You need to go thru the same steps, but create a QWORD value (instead of DWORD).

It would be nice if moderators explained their decisions instead of just removing the answers for no apparent reason.
I am new to the community and have no idea what rule I am breaking.

In this case, the above procedure solved my issue, and I wanted to share that with other users to help them also. This answer was even upvoted before being removed.

Comment: And @terdon is a brand new mod too, so he's still learning :)

Answer (score 12):

First, your answer is really a comment on another answer and not an answer in itself. That's one reason to delete. However, looking at your answer again, I realize that I should have converted it to a comment on the other answer instead of outright deleting it. I have now done so. Sorry for the confusion.

That said, this is a very old question that isn't even really on topic here. This site is about Ubuntu, so any non-Ubuntu question is off topic. An exception was made at the time for that question since it was asking for a solution to bad advice given in the official Ubuntu documentation:

> This question is asking for help reversing changes explained in a procedure documented in an Ask Ubuntu answer and in the Ubuntu community wiki. Ordinarily Windows questions should be closed as off-topic, but in this case, I do not think we should close this as off-topic. However, it might be reasonable to add information about how to reverse the Windows registry edit in that answer to that answer itself, and then make this a duplicate of that question. – Eliah Kagan Dec 25 '12 at 4:57

So, I deleted your answer because i) it seemed off topic since it was a windows thing (but that was wrong of me since it was the question itself that was off topic) and ii) because it is not really answering the question but instead only extending an already existing answer. Such things should be posted as comments and not answers.

Nevertheless, you're quite right, I should have explained my actions to you. My apologies for your abrupt treatment.

Comment: This explanation was really clarifying. I will be extra careful not to make the same mistake again. Thank you very much for this and for converting my answer to comment :)

Comment: @maaw no worries, I know the site rules can be confusing to new users, I've been there! You might want to take the [tour] or read the [help] to understand how the site works. I hope you stick around!

Answer (score 2):

Normally, there are already comments on the post itself before a mod even has to take action and even if there isn't is just asking moderators that are usually busy explain one and each of their actions. It just doesn't scale. In this case, it was obvious a comment on another answer and I don't really think the moderator that acted should have explained himself. There's a link already in your posts when they are deleted that explain most reasons [why answers can get deleted](https://askubuntu.com/help/deleted-answers).